# Partial-filling of a rectangle on Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, drawing

I am new in Silverlight. I need to fill a rectangle partially with a SolidColorBrush (like a Bar, I need the border). With GradientBrush, the change of color is not sharp.

I can add two rectangles for this, but there has to be a better way.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I am using Silverlight 4.0.

Thanks for reading.

-Rakib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using gradient brush with gradient stops very close to each other, something like this:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="_backgroundBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.65" />
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.66" />
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked (at least for what I needed). Really good trick!! It works perfect if I set the middle two offsets with same value.